# Mysqld_multi doesn't recognize groups

Tags: mysql, etc

I am trying to configure a MySQL server to run multiple instances of the daemon (I wish to duplicate it onto different drives). I've been trying to use the mysqld_multi script. However the script is not finding the groups in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`.

I copied and pasted the the configuration from `msqld_multi --example` into my.cnf, and this discovered the groups fines. However when I tried to modify the file below `mysqld_multi report` just displays:

```
Reporting MySQL servers
No groups to be reported (check your GNRs)
```

Below is an abbreviation of my my.cnf file.

```
[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld1] #this is for the master server
pid-file =/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket =/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port =3306
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
server-id=1
log-bin=mysql-bin

[mysqld2] #for the slave!
pid-file =/var/run/mysqld-slave/mysqld-slave.pid
socket =/var/run/mysqld-slave/mysqld-slave.sock
port =3307
datadir =/var/lib/mysql-backup
server-id=2
skip-innodb
default-storage-engine =myisam
[mysqld_multi]
user            = mysql

[mysqld] 
basedir         = /usr
tmpdir          = /tmp
...
```

Here's a short bit from `mysqld_multi --example`

```
[mysqld_multi]
mysqld     = /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
mysqladmin = /usr/bin/mysqladmin
user       = multi_admin
password   = my_password

[mysqld2]
socket     = /tmp/mysql.sock2
port       = 3307
...
```

Can anyone spot why mysqld_multi isn't parsing this?

Comment: Did you run `mysqld_multi start 1` and `mysqld_multi start 2`?

Comment: Yes, and it has absolutely no output. If I look in the error logs it just says it couldn't find any groups.

Comment: What's `multi_admin`'s privileges?

Comment: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 23756 Apr 19 08:38 /usr/bin/mysqld_multi`

Comment: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   1061 Apr 19 08:38 mysqld_multi.server` Also I usually run it as sudo.

Comment: No, I mean grants privileges of user `multi_admin`?

Comment: Oh none, so far I haven't set up those permissions. However it isn't really relevant as it worked with no grants with the example file. I will eventually grant the user shutdown privilege per the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the problem. Mysqld_multi can't parse comments at all, so you just need to remove all the comment lines with # before them from my.cnf.