# run multiple instances of MySQL CentOS7

Tags: linux, centos, mysql

I need to have multiple instances of MySQL running on my PC.
I did this:

> `yum install mariadb-server mariadb` => install mysql
>
> `mysql_install_db --datadir=/var/lib/mysql` => use mysql_install_db to create datadir for the first instance
>
> `mysql_install_db --datadir=/var/lib/mysql2`=> use mysql_install_db to create datadir for the second instance
>
> `chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql` chown owner-user:owner-group
>
> `chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql2` chown owner-user:owner-group

Then I modified my.cnf file for multiple instances:

```
[client]
#password       = your_password
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MariaDB server
[mysqld_multi]
mysqld = /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
mysqladmin = /usr/bin/mysqladmin

[mysqld0]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
server-id = 1
log-bin = mysql-bin
binlog_format = mixed

[mysqld2]
port            = 3307
socket          = /var/lib/mysql2/mysql.sock
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld2.pid
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql2
server_id       = 2
skip-log-bin
```

Then I used this command `mysqld_multi report` and got this:

```
Reporting MySQL servers
MySQL server from group: mysqld0 is not running
MySQL server from group: mysqld2 is not running
```

Then I used `mysqld_multi start` and `mysqld_multi report` and got the same message again:

```
Reporting MySQL servers
MySQL server from group: mysqld0 is not running
MySQL server from group: mysqld2 is not running
```

I was surfing over the Internet and found out this solutions [multiple instances](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/08/26/mysqld_multi-how-to-run-multiple-instances-of-mysql/) and [mysqld_multi](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134583/mysqld-multi-doesnt-recognize-groups). But I did not find any key to my problem.
What am I going to do to run my instances?

Comment: Standard question: is SELinux on? (Run `getenforce`.)

Comment: When I ran `getenforce` I got `Enforcing`.

Comment: Try to disable the selinuxand then restart the host. Disabling selinux need reboot

Comment: @AngRed: `setenforce 0` should do it, but you're right insofar as the persistent config is in `/etc/sysconfig/selinux`.

Comment: Regrettably, it did not give a proper effect. Nothing changed.

Comment: I think you need an automate init script for all instances upon server initialization/shutdown, now that we use mysqld_multi to control the instances, the usual /etc/init.d/mysql won’t work.

Comment: Actually, I have already tried this too. I created unit for `/etc/system/systemd`, called it `mysqld_multi.service`, enabled and started. The same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out why I couldn't start my two instances. It was necessary to comment [client] section in `/etc/my.cnf` file and wrote `unit` for `/etc/systemd/system` in a proper way.
Here is the way I did it:

> Configuration of /etc/my.cnf file:

```
[mysqld_multi]
mysqld = /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
mysqladmin = /usr/bin/mysqladmin

[mysqld1]
user    = mysql
pid-file = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port=3306
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
server_id=1
log-bin=mysql-bin
binlog_format=mixed

[mysqld2]
user = mysql
pid-file = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld2.pid
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld2.sock
port=3307
datadir=/var/lib/mysql2
server_id=2
skip-log-bin

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

> Configuration of /etc/systemd/system/mysqld_multi_service.service:

```
[Unit]
Description= mysqld_multi_service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld_multi start
ExecStop=/usr/bin/mysqld_multi stop
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then `systemctl enable mysqld_multi_service.service` and `systemctl start mysqld_multi_service.service`.
After **ALL** this steps you can connect to the first instance using this command:

> `mysql -u root -S /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`

or to the second instance:

> `mysql -u root -S /var/run/mysqld/mysqld2.sock`

Answer (score 0):

From the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/5.7/en/using-systemd.html), it looks like mysql_multi should not be used anymore:

> Because systemd has the capability of managing multiple MySQL
>   instances on platforms for which systemd support is installed,
>   mysqld_multi and mysqld_multi.server are unnecessary and are not
>   installed. This is true as of MySQL 5.7.13 for RPM platforms, 5.7.19
>   for Debian platforms.

Instead, you should use systemd to manage the instances that you setup in the `my.cnf` configuration file. See the section `Configuring Multiple MySQL Instances Using systemd` in the link provided.